# Why does "Out-File" seem to ignore the "Encoding" parameter?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I'm trying to save output to a file:

```
SFC | Out-File -FilePath out.txt
```

Now if I open `out.txt` in Notebook, I expect to see

```
You must be an administrator running a console session in order to
use the sfc utility.
```

And here is what I actually see:

```
Y o u   m u s t   b e   a n   a d m i n i s t r a t o r   r u n n i n g   a   c o n s o l e   s e s s i o n   i n   o r d e r   t o   
 
 
u s e   t h e   s f c   u t i l i t y .
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64412443/), I added `-Encoding UTF8`:

```
SFC | Out-File -FilePath out.txt -Encoding UTF8
```

but it made no difference.

My PowerShell version: `7.2.2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell 7's default output encoding is already UTF-8. The problem is not with PowerShell encoding the text into the file, but in *decoding* the text printed by the native program `sfc`. You can demonstrate this by looking at the sequence of characters before writing the file:

```
sfc | % { $_.ToCharArray() }
```

Notice the blanks between each pair of real characters—these are zero/null characters, seen by further piping through `% { [int]$_ }`. SFC is apparently printing its output in the Windows double-byte Unicode encoding, but PowerShell is interpreting it with UTF-8 or some single-byte encoding, so it sees an extra null character where SFC meant the high byte of the previous character. `Out-File` then faithfully encodes these null characters as single zero bytes in UTF-8.

The solution is to tell PowerShell that the native program will be writing its output in double-byte Unicode:

```
[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode
```

Comment: another way to see the unwanted chars is `sfc | Format-Hex`. kinda handy - it shows those extras as dots and [to me] that seems to make it more clear what is happening.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey `Format-Hex` is indeed very useful. Be careful, however, when using it with text input because it takes an `-Encoding` parameter that changes the result. I chose to look at the character sequence because that reflects only what PowerShell has already decoded.

Comment: ah! good point ... thank you for the clarification! [*grin*]